# OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, http-post, urlconnection

I am trying to build an android app for a website and I need to post some value to this page first. 
Here is my code:

```
private void sendPOST(String user,String pass) throws IOException {

        String POST_PARAMS = "username="+user+"&password="+pass;           
        URL obj = new URL("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mysite/test.php");          
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        //----------------------------------------------------------- For POST only - START---------------------------------------------

         con.setDoOutput(true);
         OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
         os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
         os.flush();
         os.close();

        // ------------------------------------------------------------For POST only - END----------------------------------------------------
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();                   
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            // print result
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString()==""?"No Result":response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"POST request failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

when this line is executed   `OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();`
a null exception occurs.
I am unable to proceed further. Please suggest what i must do to remove this exception.

Comment: Based on the information provided so far, `con` can impossibly throw NPE at that point. So it's more likely you just misinterpreted/misformulated the problem. Therefore, it would be helpful if you edit the question to paste the unmodified stack trace, just to avoid red herrings.

Comment: `java post method in android studio throws exception`. No not in Android Studio but in your app. Not java post but HttpUrlConnection post.

Comment: Remove the Toast() statements. They cannot be used together with network code. You call this code in an AsyncTask or thread? If not you have a NetworkOnMainathreadException.

Answer (score 0):

put your delevelopment server in another locatation other than `localhost` (try using the real IP, something like: `192.168.0.1`).

sometimes you will receive a successfull connection from `HttpUrlConnection.openConnection()` (it returns non null object) and this not guarantee the subsequents calls to success. In other words, when you call `con.getOutputStream()` it throws an exception no matter if `con` is non-null.

Answer (score 0):

It's the old question but I might have to answer on it because I have face to it today. When you ping http (instead https) have to put in manifest -> application: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Answer (score 0):

I think this would helped you years ago...

```
        try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = POST_PARAMS.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should try to "connect" first before doing anything with your created `HttpURLConnection con`.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.connect();
```

*do more stuff with con...*

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested but didn't work. Still getting the exception.

Answer (score -2):

```
URL obj = new URL("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mysite/test.php");
```

URL Class object "obj" can't reach to your mentioned URL properly.

Try this instead:

```
URL obj = new URL("http://"+"xx.xx.xx.xx/mysite/test.php");
```

Comment: whats the difference ?

Comment: There is no difference between these two, could you expand a bit on how this solves the problem ?